# setontouchlistener for x seconds

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use setontouchlistener. What I would like to do if I hold an imagebutton for an example 5 seconds, I get alerted... this is how I would do it:

```
    final ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // do something
            return false;
        }
    });
```

How can I implement something like this with setontouchlistener after x seconds?

Working solution:

```
imageButton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mTouchDownTime = event.getEventTime();
                    Log.v("CustomDebug", "Message: " + mTouchDownTime);

                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    long elapsedTime = event.getEventTime() - mTouchDownTime;
                    Log.v("CustomDebug", "Message: " + elapsedTime);

                }
                return false;   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onTouch gets called twice, the first time with a MotionEvent ACTION_DOWN and a second time with the MotionEvent ACTION_UP

so pseudocode:

```
if Event == ACTION_DOWN 
  saveTime = time();
elseif Event == ACTION_UP and time()-savetime > 5
  doStuff because the guy hold it for 5sec.
```

Comment: This assumes that the user lifts up after 5 seconds. If you want it to occur even if the user continues to hold down, just remove the check for  Event == ACTION_UP.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was not the solution, but I marked it because it helped me a lot. I will write the working solution in my question.